# coalesce two records into one

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, coalesce

I have a table that stores two values; 'total' and 'owing' for each customer. Data is uploaded to the table using two files, one that brings in 'total' and the other brings in 'owing'. This means I have two records for each customerID:

```
customerID:--------Total:--------- Owing:

1234----------------  1000----------NULL

1234-----------------NULL-----------200
```

I want to write a stored procedure that merges the two records together:

```
customerID:--------Total:--------- Owing:

1234----------------  1000----------200
```

I have seen examples using COALESCE so put together something like this:

```
BEGIN

-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

--Variable declarations

DECLARE @customer_id varchar(20)
DECLARE @total decimal(15,8)
DECLARE @owing decimal(15,8)
DECLARE @customer_name_date varchar(255)
DECLARE @organisation varchar(4)
DECLARE @country_code varchar(2)
DECLARE @created_date datetime

--Other Variables
DECLARE @totals_staging_id int

--Get the id of the first row in the staging table
SELECT @totals_staging_id = MIN(totals_staging_id)
from TOTALS_STAGING

--iterate through the staging table
WHILE @totals_staging_id is not null
BEGIN

update TOTALS_STAGING

SET 
total = coalesce(@total, total),
owing = coalesce(@owing, owing)

where totals_staging_id = @totals_staging_id

END
END
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: You'll need a mechanism to ensure row1 and row2 can be uniquely selected, and you'll need a mechanism to set a precedence if two values do not match but are non-null (i.e. row1.Total is 1000 and row2.Total is 2000).  Assuming you have that, my answer below will work.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.customerId, t1.total, t2.owing FROM test t1 JOIN test t2 ON ( t1.customerId = t2.customerId) WHERE t1.total IS NOT NULL AND t2.owing IS NOT NULL
```

Wondering why aren't you just using `UPDATE` on a second file execution?

Answer (score 0):

> Except for COUNT, aggregate functions ignore null values. Aggregate
>   functions are frequently used with the GROUP BY clause of the SELECT
>   statement. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx)

So you don't need to worry about null values with summing. Following will give your  **merging records together**. [Fiddle-demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b606d/3)

```
select customerId,
       sum(Total) Total,
       sum(Owing) Owing
from T
Group by customerId
```

Comment: Should that really be doing what it's doing for customerId, rather than just selecting it out?

Comment: @muhmud this is for `merging records together` or I meant as `desired output`.

Comment: Looks correct now, you had some aggregate computation for it before.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp
(
  CustomerId int,
  Total int,
  Owing int
)

insert into #Temp
values (1024,100,null),(1024,null,200),(1025,10,null)



Create Table #Final 
(
  CustomerId int,
  Total int,
  Owing int
)

insert into #Final
values (1025,100,50)



MERGE #Final AS F
USING 
(SELECT customerid,sum(Total) Total,sum(owing) owing FROM #Temp
 group by #Temp.customerid
) AS a

ON (F.customerid = a.customerid)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET F.Total = F.Total + isnull(a.Total,0)
                              ,F.Owing = F.Owing + isnull(a.Owing,0)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (CustomerId,Total,Owing)
VALUES (a.customerid,a.Total,a.owing);

select * from #Final

drop table #Temp
drop table #Final
```

Comment: The only problem with this is that the data gets updated every hour so the total/owing values can change hourly...

Comment: So I need to have a check if there to say if the customerId exists then over write the value, do not sum the two total values together

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT CustomerID, 
       COALESCE(total1, total2) AS Total, 
       COALESCE(owing1, owing2) AS Owing
FROM 
(SELECT row1.CustomerID AS CustomerID,
        row1.Total AS total1,
        row2.Total AS total2,
        row1.Owing AS owing1,
        row2.Owing AS owing2
FROM YourTable row1 INNER JOIN YourTable row2 ON row1.CustomerID = row2.CustomerID
WHERE row1.Total IS NULL AND row2.Total IS NOT NULL) temp
--Note:  Alter the WHERE clause as necessary to ensure row1 and row2 are unique.
```

...but note that you'll need some mechanism to ensure row1 and row2 are unique.  My WHERE clause is an example based on the data you provided.  You'll need to tweak this to add something more specific to your business rules.